# Is VMWare installed in the current OS?

Tags: vmware

My question is about VMWare. I read I can use VMWare to get another OS on my notebook (for example). I have a few questions:

1. Is it installed in the current OS, like any other application is?
2. Can it affect in any way the current OS?
3. I read that someone could get the OS to boot again after installing VMWare, is it possible?
4. Is the VMWare Workstation what I want?

Thank you :)

Comment: `Is the VMWare Workstation what I want?` No; a pony is what you want.  How are we supposed to know what you want?

Comment: http://www.vmware.com/products/desktop_virtualization/

Comment: At your level of information about virtualization, VMware Workstation might be the safest bet, but what you "want" might be anybody's guess.

Comment: @SLaks I don't want a pony haha. The question was if Workspace is the product from VMWare that I want to use for virtualization. They have other products as well

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, and their other products are also used for virtualization.  We have no idea which one you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are asking.
1. VMWare installs just like any other application.
2. Operating Systems running in the VM generally don't affect your data outside the VM, unless you set up syncing folder sor network shared folders.
3. I don't know how that would happen, but I can't tell you with 100% certainty that it couldn't happen to you.
4. I've been using VirtualBox for a while, mostly with linux type OSes. It's free, and I've had zero problems.

Comment: ok, so it's not installed just like another OS.

Answer (score 0):

1- Yes.

2- Only Windows and Macintosh (I'm not sure about linux).

3- Yes.

4- I don't know :-D.

Answer (score 0):

1. VMWare does not come along as a default application in the OS (Windows, Linux, MacOS). You have to download it from [here](http://downloads.vmware.com) and install it in order to get it work.
2. No. Since VMWare create a virtual machine for you. This virtual machine provides basic parts of a computer that are required to run an OS properly.
3. No idea.
4. The question isn't clear but I guess that you want to ask if there are any other applications similar to VMWare. If that's so, I suggest you [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). It's lightweight and free.

Comment: ok, I see that people don't get my last question. To rephrase it: is Workstation what I want? I want to say that VMWare has more products used for virtualization. Which one should I choose? That's the right question